# Show all hidden folders and files on my USB pendrive

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I want to improve my batch file to show all hidden folders and files of my USB pendrive !
So; my question is how to know if my variable `!MyUSB!` is defined or not to continue into my script or to exit if isn't defined ?

Here is my code :

```
@echo off
cls & color 0A & echo.
Mode con cols=75 lines=7
Title Show all hidden folders and files on your USB key by Hackoo 2016
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM  --> Check for permissions
Reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment">nul 2>&1
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo.
ECHO                    **************************************
ECHO                     Running Admin shell... Please wait...
ECHO                    **************************************

    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
Set TmpLog=Tmp.txt
Set Log=USBCopyLog.txt
If exist %TmpLog% Del %TmpLog%
If exist %TmpLog% Del %TmpLog%
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" ^|find /i ":"') do (echo %%i && Set MyUSB=%%i)
cls
echo.
echo           #########################################################
echo                  Votre cle usb connecte en tant que !MyUSB!
echo           #########################################################
echo.
pause
cls
If Defined !MyUSB! && Attrib -s -h -r !MyUSB!\*.* /S /D >> !TmpLog! 2>&1 || Exit /b
Cmd /U /C Type !TmpLog! > !Log!
Explorer "!MyUSB!\"
```

Comment: See `if /?`. Particularly `if defined`. You should learn programming in the language you are using. Batch is for deleting or copying files and starting programs. I transferred from REXX to batch in 1985.

Comment: can't you just use `set "MyUSB="` at the start and `if "!MyUSB"==""` to check if it is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code works :

```
@echo off
cls & color 0A & echo.
Mode con cols=75 lines=7
Title Show all hidden folders and files on your USB key by Hackoo 2016
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
REM  --> Check for permissions
Reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment">nul 2>&1
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo.
ECHO                    **************************************
ECHO                     Running Admin shell... Please wait...
ECHO                    **************************************

Goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::START
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Set TmpLog=%tmp%\Tmp.txt
Set Log=%tmp%\USBLog.txt
If exist %TmpLog% Del %TmpLog%
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2" ^|find /i ":"') do (Set MyUSB=%%i)
cls
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set _drive=%MyUSB%
If Exist !_drive! (
cls
echo.
echo           #########################################################
echo                        Your usb key is connected as !_drive!
echo           #########################################################
echo.
pause
Attrib -s -h -r !_drive!\*.* /S /D >> !TmpLog! 2>&1
Cmd /U /C Type !TmpLog! > !Log!
If exist !TmpLog! Del !TmpLog!
Explorer "!_drive!\"
) ELSE (
cls
color 0C
echo.
echo           #########################################################
echo                         Your usb key is not detected
echo           #########################################################
echo.
pause
Exit
)
```